# Maximum size of data which can be fetched using web service in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, web-services, actionscript-3, http, remoteobject

I want to know the size limit of data which can be fetched in case of HTTP/Webservice/RO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any file size limits are not flex specific, but instead relate to the protocols in question - which (AFAIK), there are none.

However, it's worth noting that if you send a particularly large packet size to the client, you will notice that the UI freezes while the packet is deserialized into memory within the client.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested large responses, but there are limits with sending large requests. At least with RemoteObject, the entire object must be loaded into memory so loading 2gigs would get an `OutOfMemoryError`.

Comment: Thanks you so much sharing your experience @Jacob Eggers :)